# TypeScript types for heavily nested object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I got a tree I am trying to render recursively

The tree variable is just an example it could grow much bigger depending on the data the app gets.

How can I keep TypeScript happy about the types on this tree even thou I don't know how nested is going to get?

```
const tree = {
  people: ['Managing Director'],
  children: {
    people: ['Operations Director', 'Head of Client Services'],
    children: {
      people: ['Senior Developer']
    }
  }
}

interface IList {
  people: string[],
  children: string[]
}

interface IData {
  data: IList[]
}

const List: FC<IData> = ({ data }) => (
  <ul>
    {data.people.map((person) => ( <li>{person}</li> ))}
    {!data.children ? null : <List data={data.children} />}
  </ul>
)

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <List data={tree} />
    </>
  )
}
```

When I do it on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-j9fco?file=/src/index.tsx) it works but with warnings, If I do it on my config I get

```
`Property 'people' does not exist on type 'IList[]'`
```

[EXAMPLE](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-j9fco?file=/src/index.tsx)

Comment: One thing to note about the warning you are getting on codesandbox: it isn't related to the TypeScript issue, it's because when using the an iterator, in your case `.map`, to render the tags  you need a `key` prop. So in your case: `...(<li key={person}>{person}</li>)` will make it happy. (as long as person is unique, if not, just use the index)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the `children` property optional and a recursive type:

```
type Tree = {
    people: Array<string>;
    children?: Tree;
}

const tree: Tree = {
  people: ['Managing Director'],
  children: {
    people: ['Operations Director', 'Head of Client Services'],
    children: {
      people: ['Senior Developer']
    }
  }
}
```

Then `List` can accept a prop of type `Tree` and recursively render it.

```
const List = ({ data }: { data: Tree }) => (
    <ul>
        {data.people.map((person) => (<li>{person}</li>))}
        {!data.children ? null : <List data={data.children} />}
    </ul>
)
```

Comment: I'd remove the `FC`, `IList`, and `IList` types, IMO they aren't doing anything useful for you. Just use the one `Tree` type for the prop.